# What is the alternative for AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask in Android fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, deprecated, google-pay

I am trying to integrate Google Pay into my application and all seems fine until I have to resolve the task from `PaymentClient.loadPaymentData()`. It's being called from a fragment and as far as I know `onActivityResult()` has been deprecated in favor of `registerForActivityResult()`. I can't seem to find a way to resolve the task using this function. How do I do that?

For code reference I followed this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#checkoutactivity.kt-kotlin and it recommends using `AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask()` but it uses `onActivityResult()` for its results.